# Sql query with Parent-Child Tree Hierarchy

Tags: sql-server

I have a database table, with the following data

```
Id  Level parentId Name
1   1     0        ĐẤT NÔNG NGHIỆP
2   1     0        ĐẤT PHI NÔNG NGHIỆP
3   1     0        ĐẤT CHƯA SỬ DỤNG
4   2     1        Đất sản xuất nông nghiệp
5   2     1        Đất lâm nghiệp
6   2     1        Đất nuôi trồng thủy sản
7   2     1        Đất nông nghiệp khác
8   2     2        Đất ở (nông thôn / đô thị)
9   2     2        Đất chuyên dùng
10  2     2        Đất sông, ngòi, kênh, rạch, suối và mặt nước chuyên dùng
11  2     2        Đất phi NN khác
12  2     3        Đất chưa xác định mục đích sử dụng
...
```

I want to write a query for getting data like following:

[image]

As you see, I have 6 levels. I want to get all data like above sequence but all data is as the same column.
I tried searching and found a solution: [[Parent/Child hierarchy tree view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380620/parent-child-hierarchy-tree-view])
But I'm so sorry because I didn't understand about that.
I tried changing to:

```
WITH relation(Id, IdCha, TenMucDichSuDung, [level], [orderSequence])  
AS 
(
    SELECT Id,
           IdCha,
           TenMucDichSuDung,
           0,
           CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(20))
    FROM   NhomMucDichSuDungDat 
    WHERE  IdCha = 0 
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT p.Id,
           p.IdCha,
           r.[level] + 1,
           CAST(
               r.orderSequence + '_' + CAST(p.Id AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR(20)
           )
    FROM   NhomMucDichSuDungDat p
           INNER JOIN relation r
                ON  p.IdCha = r.Id
)  

SELECT RIGHT('----------', ([level] * 3)) + TenMucDichSuDung
FROM   relation
ORDER BY
       orderSequence
```

but I got a error :

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must
>   have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

can everyone help me do this?

Comment: please format your post so that it is readable.

Comment: What do you see when you compare the number of columns in the SELECT-Lists of the two unioned queries?

Comment: I got a error, nothing to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I count the number of columns of the unioned queries I see that the first query returns five columns, the second four. That's not allowed. The unioned queries must have the same number of columns and also the datatypes must be compatible.

See: [msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms180026(v=sql.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms180026(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll review the sql query

Comment: Thanks a lot @CPMunich , I saw my query, I found the problem.
That's reason, I missed a field.